# Virtual constexpr covariant return types

Tags: c++, covariance, constexpr, c++20

As far as I can understand from [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1064r0.html) C++20 drops the restrictions on using virtual functions in constexpr contexts. The change itself is simple, the words "it shall not be virtual" were removed. The rationale for this seems to be that the dynamic type of everything has to be known already anyway, so the cost of allowing it is almost nothing.

What caught my interest was the discussion about covariance. There's an example at the end of the paper given:

> ```
> struct X1
> {
>     constexpr virtual X1 const* f() const { return this; }
> };
>
> struct Y
> {
>     int m = 0;
> };
>
> struct X2: public Y, public X1
> {
>     constexpr virtual X2 const* f() const { return this; }
> };
>
> constexpr X1 x1;
> static_assert( x1.f() == &x1 );
>
> constexpr X2 x2;
> constexpr X1 const& r2 = x2;
> static_assert( r2.f() == &r2 );
> ```

By my reading of this it's likely that `decltype(r2.f())` is meant to be `X2 const*` and not `X1 const*`. After all, if the dynamic type is completely known isn't that the simplest implementation?

So in the above example should I expect this to compile:

```
constexpr decltype(r2.f()) zz = &x1;
```

(FWIW the versions of compilers available online [seem to accept it](https://godbolt.org/z/uCRudE), which isn't what I anticipated. I asked because if this did work the way I'd expected then it would allow for some pretty funky games to be played with type erasure style techniques at compile).

Comment: The static type of an expression doesn't change.

Answer (score 4):

> After all, if the dynamic type is completely known isn't that the simplest implementation?

Just because code is invoked at compile time doesn't mean the normal rules of C++ get suspended. If the type of an expression is one thing in non-compile time code, then it will be the same if that code gets run at compile time.

At runtime, the runtime environment (whether executed at compile-time or not) knows the dynamic type of all pointer/references to objects. After all, if it didn't, `dynamic_cast` wouldn't be able to work. But that doesn't change the fact that calling a base class function will return was the base class function says that it returns, regardless of the dynamic type you happen to pass.

> FWIW the versions of compilers available online seem to accept it, which isn't what I anticipated.

It is accepted because `&x1` is of type `X1*`, and the `decltype` expression is of type `X1*`. So you're just copying an `X1*`.